# Get a blob content of a uploaded file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a file upload HTML element.

```
<input type="file" id="picture">
```

How can I get a blob content of the file every time the file is selected.
The blob should be such that, it can be set as an src attribute for an image Html element to display it on the web page, then and there.

Comment: nope, the question is edited, read again.

Comment: @AnjalBinayak It's easy to find those duplicates if you search it in simple terms on google ("preview image before upload javascript")